# Extensive-form games (Game theory)

Tags: game-theory

Would you please help me with these questions?

1. Is it possible to convert any dynamic game to strategic form? is there any proof? or is there any Counterexample?
2. Could we consider a dynamic game in extensive form to be able to start the game with more than one player? And if it is, can you name one example please?

Answer (score 0):

1st part: We can model any dynamic game into a strategic form, but we may lose information. For example, the model may lack the sequence of choices and order of players.

2nd part: by definition, the extensive form is a tree. so, if two players start a game the two sides of the tree join after a couple of moves or don't. if they join, by definition the tree structure is gone and we have a graph and also we don't know which player will make a move after the conjunction node. Also, if they do not join, we just have two games.

Comment: I want to let you know that your advice is very much appreciated.